# Como utilizar da meneira correta o MutationObserver()?

Tags: javascript, dom

Eu sei que o `MutationObserver()` foi desenvolvido para detectar alterações no DOM do HTML.

Mas gostaria de saber como isso funciona na prática.

Criamos uma situação hipotética, que tal?

Existe uma `<div>` com `id='hipotese'` *(acredito que ela será observada pelo seu `id`, correto?)*

Está `<div>` possuí diversos outros conteúdos dentro dela, que são gerados dinamicamente. *(não temos controle da quantidade de conteúdo gerado dentro dela)*

O que acontece é que existem diversos métodos que atuam nesses conteúdos dinâmicos. *(recebem diversos parâmetros vindo desses conteúdos)*

No Google Chrome podemos apertar o F12 e sair alterando os atributos deste conteúdo da forma que bem entendermos. E depois de alterados quando acontecesse a chamada dos métodos, os retornos não seriam como o esperado *(gerados de forma dinâmica)*

-- Fim da situação hipotética --

Como eu consigo observar e detectar a menor e mais simples mudança nestes elementos presentes em nossa `<div id='hipotese'>` ?

Existe alguma outra forma de detectar essa alteração?

*Sei que o usuário pode desativar o `JavaScript`, mas nada que não possa ser resolvido com o `<noscript>`*

Comment: A parte "*O que acontece é que existem diversos métodos que atuam nesses conteúdos dinâmicos*" ficou particularmente confusa para mim. Esses métodos são funções que alteram o conteúdo com base nele próprio, visto que os parâmetros vem deste?

Answer (score 4):

Quando você registra a instância para receber notificações com o método [observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#observe()) você pode passar um objeto especificando quais mutações que devem ser observadas.

Você pode ver as opções disponíveis em [MutationObserverInit](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit).

Abaixo segue um snippet exemplificando as alterações.

```js
var hipotese = document.getElementById('hipotese');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log('mutation.type = ' + mutation.type);
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
     for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
        console.log('  "' + mutation.addedNodes[i].textContent + '" adicionado');
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < mutation.removedNodes.length; i++) {
        console.log('  "' + mutation.removedNodes[i].textContent + '" removido');
      }
    } else {
     console.log('  "' + mutation.attributeName + '" alterado')
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(hipotese, {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true
});

hipotese.className = 'pai';
var filho = document.createElement('div');
filho.textContent = 'filho';
hipotese.appendChild(filho);
filho.className = 'filho';
filho.dataset.teste = 'teste';
hipotese.removeChild(filho);
```

```html
<div id="hipotese"></div>
```